# Swipe card when button clicks in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I am currently building a mobile application like tinder using react native, I use Deck Swiper from native base package and I don't find a solution on how to swipe card when then button clicks.

This link is the Deck Swiper Component from native base that I've been using: http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.5.13/components#deckSwiper

Any suggestions or idea on how to swipe cards with button click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to save the reference of the `DeckSwiper` component:

```
<DeckSwiper ref={(deck) => this.deck = deck}>
```

Later, you can use `this.deck.swipeRight()` or `this.deck.swipeLeft`.